# Linux script capture terminal in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, record

I wrote a shell script in linux named script.sh. It suppose to call "script -a record.txt" command when being executed and create a capture of my terminal in a file called record.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

script -a record.txt

mkdir folder
```

when i run this script.sh file, i get the record.txt file created but the content "mkdir folder" is not recorded in there. the "mkdir folder" command was ignored and thus did not let me create a new directory. anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is his script.sh, the `script` in his code is a unix [command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it

```
#!/bin/bash
function one {

mkdir folder
}

one | tee record.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: The  script  command  forks  and  creates a sub-shell, according to the value of $SHELL, and records the text from  this  session.

You need to do a `Ctrl + D`, or `exit` after you have finished running your script.sh file for `script` to exit

From the `script` man page (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html)

> script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.
>
> The script ends when the forked shell exits (a control-D to exit the Bourne shell (sh(1)), and exit, logout or control-d (if ignoreeof is not
>        set) for the C-shell, csh(1)).

Hence, if you do

```
#!/bin/bash
script -a record.txt
mkdir folder
ls
```

Then the mkdir command does not get executed because you are in a separately forked sub shell now. Once you exit using `ctrl + D`, or `exit`, the `mkdir` will automatically run, and create the required folder.

However, the output of the `ls` command , or the issuing of `mkdir` and `ls` commands will not be recorded in the record.txt file since the ls is executing in the original shell, and not in the sub shell created by script.

Comment: how do i make it so that it is executing from subshell created by script?

Comment: @NewFile What are you trying to achieve? Checking your answer, `script` is the wrong tool to use in your script.